# How to check if given parameter is cv::noArray()?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv-mat

I want to implement a function that takes an image as optional parameter.
In case an image is passed, I want to use it - otherwise I want to calculate a default value. In the OpenCV library `cv::noArray()` is used for this purpose.
Something like this:

```cpp
void doStuff(cv::InputArray candidatesMap = cv::noArray())
{
    // initialize candidatesMap if not given
    if(candidatesMap is cv::noArray())  // <-- Need help here
    {
        candidatesMap = createCandidatesMap();
    }

    // ... more code using candidatesMap
}
```

How can I programmatically check if the optional parameter is given or defaults to `cv::noArray()`.

Since I didn't find any documentation, it might be helpful for others as well.

Comment: Try `.empty()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to check if an `cv::InputArray` was assigned to `cv::noArray()`:

```
void doStuff(cv::InputOutputArray candidatesMap = cv::noArray())
{
    // initialize candidatesMap if not given
    if(candidatesMap.empty())
    {
        candidatesMap = createCandidatesMap();
    }

    // ... more code using candidatesMap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the usage of the `cv::noArray()` in the OpenCV code and there is something like this:

```
if (&argument == &noArray())
    return "InputArrayOfArrays: noArray()";
```

in your case it would be probably:

```
void doStuff(cv::InputArray candidatesMap = cv::noArray())
{
    // initialize candidatesMap if not given
    if(&candidatesMap == &cv::noArray())
    {
        candidatesMap = createCandidatesMap();
    }
    // ... more code using candidatesMap
}
```

But even if `candidatesMap` is not equal to `noArray` it doesn't mean that this input is not empty. So it's also worth checking its size.

@MichałWalenciak Said that this comparison wouldn't work. So you can check it in other ways.
To check if `candidatesMap` is valid, you can call `candidatesMap.getObj()` and check if this pointer is valid or not.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak These comparations are used in the OpenCV code, so I think that should works. And the `cv::noArray()` is a just global object of an empty `_InputOutputArray`

Comment: Address of function's argument will never be equal to any other variable address in valid c/c++ code.

Comment: @Raffallo Can you point to the corresponding lines in the source code from Github? This would help to understand what is done.

Comment: @Catree `bindings_utils.cpp` line 13, 43, 80 and 110 in the OpenCV 3

Answer (score -2):

I know it doesn't answer your question, but you can solve your problem by writting cleaner code. Just write two functions. One with parameter and one without.

Comment: That might work, but I'm particularly interested in the functionality of `cv::noArray()`

Comment: Then you cannot. `candidatesMap` is of type `cv::InputArray` and you cannot tell how was it constructed. The only thing you can do is to check `candidatesMap` state. I have never used this type so I cannot tell you for sure, but I'd guess if it was constructed as `noArray` then its size will be 0. Or you can try to compare `candidatesMap` with `cv::InputArray`